# Что означает следующий синтаксис?

Tags: php

```
$db = &DB::connect($dsn, $properties);
```

Почему нельзя написать просто так:

```
$db = new DB();
$db->connect($dsn,$properties);
....
....
//receive an orgasm
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На дружественном сайте обсуждалась тема: [Constructors vs Factory Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628950/constructors-vs-factory-methods).

**UPD:**

[Static factory methods vs. constructors](http://blog.codefront.net/2003/06/21/java-tip-2-static-factory-methods-vs-constructors/) + [перевод](http://cloud-cuckoo.com.ua/content/ispolzuite-staticheskie-fabrichnye-metody-vmesto-konstruktorov)

В статьях речь идёт о яве, но в принципе эти тезисы применимы и к PHP. В данной ситуации, например, метод connect может вернуть уже существующий объект соединения с базой данных - и не надо будет соединяться по-новой. Или он может вернуть разные типы объектов. Например, Zend_Db в зависимости от переданной конфигурации, возвращает объекты того или иного класса (в зависимости от типа БД)